# How do I stop objects from Overlapping in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when my objects spawn into world they can move around each other. The only problem is that they can overlap when they move, i.e the sprite of one object moves onto the sprite of the other as show below:

http://prntscr.com/np1hs4

How would I be able to avoid this?

Comment: Use the physics engine and add colliders to them. Or write your custom engine as I did.

Comment: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/collider-2d

Comment: Notice there are 2d colliders and regular (3d) colliders. If your game is 2d, use 2d. If not, use normal colliders.

Comment: Also, in the future please write what you have attenpted already. And post screenshots for clarity. Otherwise people will downvote for poor effort. Also, if any scripts are relevant include those. Other than that, welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Hi, thanks or your reply. They already do. That doesn't work. @Doh09

Comment: Try add a Rigidbody to one of them

Comment: They already had rigid bodies attached by the way. No Luck. @Doh09

Answer (score 0):

Check if colliders are trigger or remove all components from gameobject and just leave only rigidbody and colliders. Rigidbody and colliders should be of the same type rigidbody 2d collider2d. Hope it helps!